# Google Bigquery: How do I divide 2 values in the same column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a 2 column table:

```
Category | Count
Total      100
Red        30
Blue       40
Yellow     30
```

How would you write a query to generate the following output?
I can only come up with 1 step:

1) Getting Percent column - Round(Red count/Total count)*100)

Hope to get your help to get the output below. Thanks!

```
Category | Count | Percent
Total      100     100
Red        30      30
Blue       40      40
Yellow     30      30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       count * 100.0 / max(case when category = 'Total' then count end) over () as percent
from t
```

Comment: may i know why it's necessary to have MAX() when category = 'total' which is the highest value in the column?

Comment: @dave . . . Presumably, there is only one value with `total`, and that expression returns that value.

Comment: This just solved my challenge as well. Thank you for sharing your knowledge, Gordon. Happily upvoting this.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT t.*, ROUND(t.Count * 100.0 / total.Count) Percent
FROM t, (SELECT Count FROM t WHERE category = 'Total') total
```

You can test / play with it using dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 'Total' Category, 100 Count UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Red', 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Blue', 40 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Yellow', 30 
)
SELECT t.*, ROUND(t.Count * 100.0 / total.Count) Percent
FROM t, (SELECT Count FROM t WHERE category = 'Total') total
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mikhail. 

Regarding:

    FROM t, (SELECT Count FROM t WHERE category = 'Total') total

Is this a CROSS JOIN of t and table total? The end outcome is:

    t.category | t.count | total.Count

Comment: expression `(SELECT Count FROM t WHERE category = 'Total')` gives you the table with just one row which is the value of Total (assuming of course  - there is only one row with value Total). Then, this one row being joined to each and every row in table t, giving you ability to use your formula exactly as in your question `Round(Red count/Total count)*100)`